# Document not archiving in Opentext Archive Server 10.5

Tags: ecm, opentext

Documents are not getting archived from external directory to pipeline.
After putting the document in external directory, the LOG file is gone but leaving behind the remaining 3 files.
While looking the tomcat AS logs following is the error and warning:

> - ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-5] com.opentext.ecm.asm.objects.ReqCounter -- 128 . inc ReqCounter.java:55 Security Alert: At least 5  requests with wrong docid occurred from the same client
> - WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-7] com.opentext.ecm.asm.rcs.service.impl.DocumentServiceImplHelper -- Cannot access document with id.

Following are the warnings in Prepdoc file:

> - WRN     0 18:32:07.671 ............... Dsh::getHostAndAidObject dsh.cxx-19100 archive 'ZO' is not accessable (access mode = 'c') on server of type 'orc' (o=original,r=replication,c=cache)
> - WRN     0 18:32:07.671 .............. Dsh::dsReserveDocId
>   dsh.cxx-14006 cannot get host for archive 'ZO' and access mode 'c';
>   the call of function getHostAndAidObject() failed

Answer (score 0):

Go to the archive location and check for the doc id.. use command prompt to dinfo to see if you still have the error.